# K_UP no esta definido

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Tengo un problema con las siguientes lineas:

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

if keys[K_LEFT]:
```

cuando ejecuto el código me da un error que dice:

```
File "HardGame1.1.0.py", line 49, in <module>
    if evento_tecla[K_UP]:
NameError: name 'K_UP' is not defined
```

y no entiendo porque dice que no esta definido.

Aqui el codigo:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

ventana = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 640))

class jugador(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):

        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) 


        self.image = pygame.image.load('cuadradito.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.vel = 2




    def move(self):

        if self.rect.left <= 0:
            self.rect.left = 0

        elif self.rect.right >= 640:
            self.rect.right = 640                   


Player = jugador()

while True:

    Player.move()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[K_LEFT]:
        Player.rect.top = Player.rect.top =- Player.vel
```

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar los imports? En principio te falta indicar el namespace de la constante: `keys[pygame.K_UP]`.

Comment: ya añadí todo el codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La causa del error se debe a que no tienes agregado el espacio de nombres necesario para usar las constantes de las teclas. Estas constantes (y otras usadas por PyGame) son automáticamente expuestas en el namespace `pygame`, es decir, si importas mediante `import pygame` deberías hacer:

```
keys[pygame.K_UP]
```

Otra opción es usar el módulo [`pygame.locals`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/locals.html#module-pygame.locals):

```
from pygame.locals import *

keys[K_UP]
```

Un ejemplo basado en tu código sería:

```
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *


class Jugador(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Jugador, self).__init__() 
        self.image = pygame.image.load('cuadradito.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.vel = 2


    def update(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed() 

        if keys[K_LEFT]: 
           self.rect.x -= self.vel 
           if self.rect.left <= 0:
               self.rect.left = 0

        if keys[K_RIGHT]: 
           self.rect.x += self.vel 
           if self.rect.right >= 640:
               self.rect.right = 640

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

pygame.init()
ventana = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 640))
player = Jugador()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
           pygame.quit()
           sys.exit()

    player.update()
    ventana.fill((0,0,0))
    player.draw(ventana)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```